# Pivot concatenated string

Tags: sql-server

My Input Table is

```
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| userid | teamname |  task1   | task2 |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
|    101 | T1       | 101task1 | desc1 |
|    101 | T1       | 101task2 | desc2 |
|    101 | T2       | 101task1 | desc3 |
|    101 | T2       | 101task2 | desc4 |
|    101 | T2       | 101task2 | desc5 |
|    102 | T3       | 102task1 | desc6 |
|    102 | T3       | 102task2 | desc7 |
|    102 | T3       | 102task3 | desc8 |
|    102 | T3       | 102task4 | desc9 |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

I want the output as follow, to pivot(dynamic) task1+task2

```
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| userid | teamname |       1        |       2        |       3        |       4        |
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|    101 | T1       | 101task1 desc1 | 101task2 desc2 |                |                |
|    101 | T2       | 101task1 desc3 | 101task2 desc4 | 101task2 desc5 |                |
|    102 | T3       | 102task1 desc6 | 102task2 desc7 | 102task3 desc8 | 102task4 desc9 |
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I tried to pivot task1 and it worked like sample code [SampleCode](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1125632),

but when I pivot `max(task1+task2)` I get error

Comment: What error? What was your attempt? We can't tell you why a piece of code is generating an error, if we don't know what that code is, or the error you are getting.

Comment: you can see the attempt is in the sample code in the question.

Comment: What sample code? `max(task1+task2)` won't generate an error on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine them in source of pivot table and use them by giving them an alias.

```
set @query = 'SELECT userid,teamname,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
         select userid,
                teamname,
                concat(task1,task2) as col, --Combine here
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid,teamname order by task1 asc) AS Row#
            from #yt
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(col)  --Alias used here
            for row# in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query);
```

**Edit :** To add a space in between fields

```
set @query = 'SELECT userid,teamname,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
         select userid,
                teamname,
                CONCAT(task1,SPACE(1),task2) col,
                ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY userid,teamname order by task1 asc) AS Row#
            from #yt
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(col)
            for row# in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Comment: Thanks,How can I add space In concat(task1,task2) ? when I write it like this concat(task1," ",task2) it doesnt work